# DataMapper save fails but with no errors

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

When I try to modify and then save a model using DataMapper I get a SaveFailure exception but no errors.

Specifically I see this message:
"MonthlyBill#save returned false, MonthlyBill was not saved"

This is the code doing the saving:

```
post '/monthly_bills' do
  with_authenticated_user do |user|
  description = params[:description]
  expected_amount = params[:expected_amount]
  pay_period = params[:pay_period]

  monthly_bill = MonthlyBill.new(:description=>description, :expected_amount=>expected_amount, :pay_period=>pay_period)
  user.monthly_bills << monthly_bill
  user.save
end
```

The User model:

```
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,             Serial
  property :email_address,  String
  property :password,       String

  has n, :monthly_bills
  has 1, :current_pay_period
end
```

The MonthlyBill model:

```
class MonthlyBill
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,             Serial
  property :description,    String
  property :expected_amount,Decimal
  property :pay_period,     Integer

  belongs_to :user
end
```

What is the issue and, more importantly, how can I get DataMapper to tell me more specifically what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm - those capitalised properties look worrying to me. I would do...

```
has n, :monthly_bills 
has 1, :current_pay_period #do you really have a CurrentPayPeriod model?!
```

And then try:

```
monthly_bill = MonthlyBill.new(:description=>description,:expected_amount=>expected_amount, :pay_period=>pay_period, :user=>user)
monthly_bill.save
```

Comment: lol I do... There's not a programmatic way in my problem domain to detect a pay period...

Comment: also I made the changes you suggested and I still have the same error. I did however leave my MonthlyBill class capitalized. Is that ok?

Comment: STDERR.puts monthly_bill.errors.inspect unless monthly_bill.valid? and did you remove the user.monthly_bills << line?

Comment: I overlooked trying monthly_bill.save

Comment: so now I am getting my errors... fixed one and another is about some property not being set when it doesn't even exist in my model... thanks for helping me move forward! :)

Comment: great - glad we got it sorted. Make sure your model is in sync with your actual database structure...

Comment: Yup. All set and back in control. Thanks!